# How do I configure Windows Remote Assistance through Group Policy?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7

Our Domain Controllers run on Server 2008 R2 and the majority of our client machines run Windows 7.

We are going to be moving our office to two different locations and I need to be able to offer remote assistance to their machines so I can solve helpdesk issues from my location.

I'm usually the Mac OS/Linux guy, but our Windows guy quit so I'm trying to learn and take over the windows responsibly as well, so I'm pretty new to the GPO stuff.

Answer (score 2):

The Remote Assistance can be found in **Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Remote Assistance**. You'll need to ensure that the firewall on the Windows 7 machines will allow the traffic through as well.

You can control the firewall of your clients by modifying the following GPO **Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Network > Windows Firewall**

More information on this setting can be found [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301527)

Comment: are there roles or features that i need to enable before doing this?

Comment: @user102825 - if your local computer is running Windows 7, you can install the [Remote Server Administration Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887), which will allow you to install individual management tools as required, which will then allow you to do this from your local computer. Otherwise, you need to log on to your domain controller, which will have the GPO roles already installed.

Comment: The GPM tool/console is a Feature in W2K8 and I don't believe it's installed by default with the AD DS Role.

Comment: @joeqwerty While you are correct that it is a feature in W2K8, I'm almost positive it gets installed automatically when the server is promoted to a domain controller. I have an almost stock VM that was promotes and the feature was installed.